# How can I allow both anonymous and forms authentication with an AD backend on an ASP.Net Web-Application

Tags: c#, iis-7, active-directory, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.0

I am developing an ASP.Net 4.0 Web-Application and need to allow anonymous access to all of the pages, however I want to add Forms Authentication backed by Active Directory to display additional (privileged) content when the user logs in. I've scoured the Internet looking for examples of how to do this but have come up empty handed.

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working... When I click Login, it redirects to the main page, and I can use Cookies Manager+ to see that the cookie has been created, but it still displays the Anonymous template. I imagine I'm probably going about this all wrong... Is there anyways to fix what I have to make it work, or are there any examples of this type of authentication I work from?

**LdapAuthentication.cs**

```
public class LadpAuthentication
{
    private string _path;
    private string _filterAttribute;

    public LadpAuthentication( string path )
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated( string domain, string username, string pwd )
    {
        string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry( _path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

        try
        { 
            // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
            Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if(null == result)
                return false;
            // Update the new path to the user in the directory
            _path = result.Path;
            _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

        if( null != Request["logout"] )
        {
            string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
            HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
            authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            return;
        }

        string username = Request["username"];
        string password = Request["password"];

        if( username != null && password != null )
        {
            LadpAuthentication ldap = new LadpAuthentication(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogonServer"]);
            if( ldap.IsAuthenticated("mydomain", username, password) )
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), false, null);
                string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
                Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
            else
                test.Text = "Invalid username and/or password.";
        }
    }
```

**Login.aspx**

```
<asp:Label ID="test" runat="server" />
<form action="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Login.aspx") %>" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

**Global.asax.cs**
        void Application_AuthenticateRequest( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {

```
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        if( null == authCookie )
            return;
        try {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            GenericIdentity gid = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "LdapAuthentication");
            Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(gid,null);
        } catch( Exception ex ) {

        }
    }
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <a id="login-button" href="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Login.aspx") %>" class="ui-button">Login</a>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:LoginName runat="server" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: If you're using AD use Windows authentication and impersonation

Comment: Many of the client computers are workgroup (i.e. non-domain) computers, so Windows Authentication is not really an option. I need Anonymous + Forms.